# PHP How to display array value inside ternary operators

Tags: php, arrays, embed, ternary-operator

I'm trying to display values from an array when using ternary operators but it display just an empty field.

From this line:

`".($row["Risc"] = '' ? '' : "<li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Risc</li>")."`

I get this output: Risc

Meaning that the field is not empty but when I try to display the array value it shows nothing

```
".($row["Risc"] = '' ? '' : "<li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> ". $row['Risc'] ."</li>")."`

Below the full code:

<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'>
  <ul>
  ".($row["Risc"] = '' ? '' : "<li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Risc</li>")."
  ".($row["Cond"] = '' ? '' : "<li><i class='fa fa-check'> Cond</i> Condizioni</li>")."
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Balcony</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Bedding</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Cable TV</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Cleaning after exit</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Cofee pot</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Computer</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Cot</li>
  </ul>
</div>>
```

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hi,
not working but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

`$row["Risc"] =` is a typo, it should be `$row["Risc"] ==`

In first case your assigning an empty string to `$row["Risc"]` and then, as this will result in a false value **but you are overriding the original value with an assignment**, so you obtain back an empty string.

Btw, maybe, is more suitable for you to check this

```
empty($row["Risc"])
```

read more about [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: an empty string results as false - so the else part of the tenerary is used.

Comment: No!! The result of the assignment is returned - which is in this case an empty string. Otherwise code like this wouldn't work as expected `$a = $b = 1;`

Comment: @Philipp yes, you're right. didn't get what you was saying here

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'>
  <ul>
  <?php 
  echo $row["Risc"] == ""? "" : "<li><i class='fa fa-check'> Cond</i>". $row["Risc"]."</li>" ;
  echo $row["Cond"] == ""? "" : "<li><i class='fa fa-check'> Cond</i>". $row["Cond"]."</li>" ;
          ?>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Balcony</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Bedding</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Cable TV</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Cleaning after exit</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Cofee pot</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Computer</li>
    <li><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Cot</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```